# Why cannot read excel file version older than 2013 with XML SDK 2.0 C#

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

So I wrote some code basically trying to read excel file using XML SDK. And here is the code I wrote with C# on Visual Studio 2010. I put my code at the bottom but basically the problem I am having is it will read any excel file that is 2013 version. Any excel version older than 2013 will not read. More specially the program will not go into the foreach loop when the excel version is older than 2013. Any ideas why?

```
    static void ReadExcelFile(string fileName)
    {
        //open the file
        using (SpreadsheetDocument myDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, true))
        {
            //workbook part captcure
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = myDoc.WorkbookPart;

            //then access to the worksheet part
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();

            //find sheet data
            SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();


            foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
            {

                foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
                {
                    string text = c.CellValue.Text;

                    Console.WriteLine(text); 
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: @Tarik No error messages, just nothing prints out on the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. Here I have provide a self explanatory code sample.

I have tested this with Excel 2010 version. It seems to me that MSDN state your version only applicable to Excel 2013 and only applies if cells contains numbers. In the given example rather than using LINQ to get elements I have manually walk through parts.

```
//open the file
using (SpreadsheetDocument myDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(path, true))
{
     //Get workbookpart
     WorkbookPart workbookPart = myDoc.WorkbookPart;

     // Extract the workbook part
     var stringtable = workbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().FirstOrDefault();

    //then access to the worksheet part
    IEnumerable<WorksheetPart> worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts;

    foreach (WorksheetPart WSP in worksheetPart)
    {
        //find sheet data
        IEnumerable<SheetData> sheetData = WSP.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>();

       foreach (SheetData SD in sheetData)
       {
            foreach (Row row in SD.Elements<Row>())
            {
                // For each cell we need to identify type
                foreach (Cell cell in row.Elements<Cell>())
                {
                    if (cell.DataType == null && cell.CellValue != null)
                    {
                         // Check for pure numbers
                         Console.WriteLine(cell.CellValue.Text);
                    }
                     else if (cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.Boolean)
                    {
                         // Booleans
                         Console.WriteLine(cell.CellValue.Text);
                     }
                    else if (cell.CellValue != null)
                    {
                         // A shared string
                         if (stringtable != null)
                         {
                          // Cell value holds the shared string location
                          Console.WriteLine(stringtable.SharedStringTable.ElementAt(int.Parse(cell.CellValue.Text)).InnerText);
                         }
                     }
                     else { 
                           Console.WriteLine("A broken book");
                     }
                 }
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: Hey, I know you've posted it a long time ago but I was wondering why do I need `SharedStringTablePart `, what is the logic of it? I mean why do I get int values instead of the string I can see when I read the excel sheet?